# How to show errors in Logger list SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I just set up a new site in SharePoint 2010 and no matter what the error shows in the frontend it is not getting registered in the logger list and when I go to the logger list I am seeing it is empty. Could you please advise what could be the error and what should I change to see errors being logged in the logger list?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Regards,
Prabhu

Comment: I hope you are looks at the logs in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint doesn't log errors in any Lists. For log you have go to following folder "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS".
For more info check following link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798395.aspx

You have write code in your custom application to log exceptions in Logger List.

Comment: I did write a custom code to save the logs but even after that also it is not logging the errors where it should. Any idea what should be done?

Comment: Could you please share the code?

Answer (score 3):

You have two types of logs in SharePoint `diagnostic logs` and `usage health data collection service usage logs` **

- `Diagnostic logging` : used to troubleshoot the SharePoint farm environment.
- `Usage health data collection service usage logs` : used to show how SharePoint is used.

The main aim for these logs is to  troubleshoot the SharePoint farm environment and monitoring and ensure the healthy of SharePoint 2013 environment.

- Based on your error and the correlation ID you can use [ULS Viewer](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/15/uls-viewer-tool/) to trace the error details that located at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs`
- You can also check event viewer.

If you are now working with production environment , you can set `CallStack` to `true` and `customErrors` to `OFF` at the web config SharePoint, this will enable you to see the errors in details.

**Steps:**

- Modify Web.config file of SharePoint Web Application that located in `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ PortNum`.
- Open Config file that located in `\\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\` PortNum.
- Search for “CallStack” and set it to True as the following:

> ```
> <SafeMode  CallStack=”false” > to <SafeMode CallStack=”true” >
> ```

- Search for “customErrors” and set mode to Off as the following:

> ```
> <customErrors mode=”On” /> to <customErrors mode=”Off” />
> ```

- Search for “debug” and set mode to True as the following:

> ```
> <compilation batch=”false” debug=”false”> to <compilation batch=”false” debug=”true”>
> ```

See also

- [Configure Trace Logs in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/15/uls-viewer-tool/)
- [How to enable debugging in SharePoint Solutions ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/02/29/debugging-sharepoint-solutions/)